# didSelectItemAtIndexPath in not called in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

i have collection view which contains image view and button in every cell where i click on imageView didSelectItemAtIndexPath is called when click on button it does not call

here is code

```
       override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell
    let sharedImageCache = FICImageCache.sharedImageCache()
    cell.imageView.image = nil
    let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(90, 90, 15, 15)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    //cell.contentView.addSubview(button)
    let photo = photos[indexPath.row] as PhotoInfo
    if (cell.photoInfo != photo) {

        sharedImageCache.cancelImageRetrievalForEntity(cell.photoInfo, withFormatName: formatName)

        cell.photoInfo = photo

       // cell.contentView.addSubview(button)

    }
    sharedImageCache.retrieveImageForEntity(photo, withFormatName: formatName, completionBlock: {
        (photoInfo, _, image) -> Void in
        if (photoInfo as! PhotoInfo) == cell.photoInfo {
           // cell.imageView.image = image
            var imgView = UIImageView(image:image!)
            imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
            cell.contentView.addSubview(imgView)

            cell.contentView.addSubview(button)
        }
    })

    return cell
}


  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let photoInfo = photosVideo[indexPath.row]
    var url = photoInfo.sourceImageURL
           button.addTarget(self, action: "showNotice", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("show photo", sender: ["photoInfo": photoInfo])
    println("hello")
}
```

Comment: `button.addTarget(self, action: "showNotice", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` Have you create the showNotice function ?

`func showNotice(sender: UIButton!) {
     println("BUTTON HERE")
}
`

Comment: Why are you adding the target in the button in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath? You need to create the action when you create the button in cellForItemAtIndexPath, and (I am not really sure here as I am not sure what you want to do) but I believe that you don't need didSelectItemAtIndexPath as something should happen when you touch the button and not the view

Comment: i will do it but its does not work

Comment: i want to use value of indexPath so i add button target in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`didSelectItemAtIndexPath` will not call when you click on button so that you have to do it different way like I mentioned below:

1. when you are create a button into `cellForItemAtIndexPath` just add a tag with it this way:

   ```
   button.tag = indexPath.row
   ```
2. After that you have to add action which is called when button is pressed:

   ```
   button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   ```
3. after that when you press button into cell you can call this method:

   ```
   func buttonTapAction(sender:UIButton!)
   {
       var button : UIButton = sender as! UIButton
       var row : Int = button.tag

       println(row)
   }
   ```

So this way you can get value of `indexPath`.

For more reference you can refer [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/TableViewCell-With-Button) example which used tableview but it will help you for better understanding.

Comment: Hi,  we know other way to fix , but collection view common property know cellForItemAtIndexPath ? its not calling, please let me know why,  now am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "showNotice", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

with this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "showNotice:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: my problem is when i click on button which in cell click on it didSelectItemAtIndexPath method does not call